# adjacency list from JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, adjacency-list, jointjs

I try to programmaticly generate a new object as a adjacency list from the following provided sampleData to be used in jointJS, so it generates a organization chart in the end:

```
sampleData = [
    {"id":"1224286", "label":"someLabel1", "image":"male.png", "level":"1"},
    {"id":"1166041", "label":"someLabel2", "image":"male.png","refparent":"1224286", "level":"2"},
    {"id":"1224376", "label":"someLabel3", "image":"male.png","refparent":"1224286", "level":"2"},
    {"id":"1317500", "label":"someLabel4", "image":"male.png", "refparent":"1224286", "level":"2"},
    {"id":"1232930", "label":"someLabel5", "image":"male.png", "refparent":"1166041", "level":"3"},
    {"id":"1163148", "label":"someLabel6", "image":"male.png", "refparent":"1317500", "level":"3"},
    {"id":"1279087", "label":"someLabel7", "image":"male.png", "refparent":"1166041", "level":"3"},
    {"id":"1185740", "label":"someLabel8", "image":"male.png","refparent":"1224376", "level":"3"},
    {"id":"1234273", "label":"someLabel9", "image":"male.png", "refparent":"1232930", "level":"4"},
    {"id":"1210593", "label":"someLabel10", "image":"male.png", "refparent":"1185740", "level":"4"},
    {"id":"1279247", "label":"someLabel11", "image":"male.png", "refparent":"1185740", "level":"4"},
    {"id":"1316785", "label":"someLabel12", "image":"male.png", "refparent":"1232930", "level":"4"},
    {"id":"1266325", "label":"someLabel13", "image":"male.png", "refparent":"1210593", "level":"5"}
];
```

The sampleData should be converted as in the following structure to use it as an adjacency list :

```
var list = {
    '1224286': ['1166041', '1224376', '1317500'],
    '1166041': ['1232930', '1279087'],
    '1224376': ['1185740'],
    '1317500': ['1163148'],
    '1232930': ['1234273', '1316785'],
    '1163148': [],
    '1279087': [],
    '1185740': ['1210593', '1279247'],
    '1234273': [],
    '1210593': ['1266325'],
    '1279247': [],
    '1316785': [],
    '1266325': []
};
```

It is looking so simple but i just can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code (has n*n complexity)

```
var output = {};
sampleData.forEach(function(val){
  var id = val.id;
  var arr = [];
  sampleData.forEach(function(innerVal){
    if ( innerVal.refparent == id )
    {
       arr.push(innerVal.id);
    }
  });
  output[id] = arr;
});
console.log(output);
```

Or else you can transform the data-structure to get better performance

```
var transformed = {};
sampleData.forEach(function(val){
  var ref = val.refparent;
  transformed[ref] = transformed[ref] || [];
  transformed[ref].push(val.id);
});
```

//now iterate the original list to see what is missed out

```
var output = {}; 
sampleData.forEach(function(val){ 
  output[val.id] = transformed[val.id] || [];
});
```

This gives you 2n complexity.

**DEMO**

```js
var sampleData = [
    {"id":"1224286", "label":"someLabel1", "image":"male.png", "level":"1"},
    {"id":"1166041", "label":"someLabel2", "image":"male.png","refparent":"1224286", "level":"2"},
    {"id":"1224376", "label":"someLabel3", "image":"male.png","refparent":"1224286", "level":"2"},
    {"id":"1317500", "label":"someLabel4", "image":"male.png", "refparent":"1224286", "level":"2"},
    {"id":"1232930", "label":"someLabel5", "image":"male.png", "refparent":"1166041", "level":"3"},
    {"id":"1163148", "label":"someLabel6", "image":"male.png", "refparent":"1317500", "level":"3"},
    {"id":"1279087", "label":"someLabel7", "image":"male.png", "refparent":"1166041", "level":"3"},
    {"id":"1185740", "label":"someLabel8", "image":"male.png","refparent":"1224376", "level":"3"},
    {"id":"1234273", "label":"someLabel9", "image":"male.png", "refparent":"1232930", "level":"4"},
    {"id":"1210593", "label":"someLabel10", "image":"male.png", "refparent":"1185740", "level":"4"},
    {"id":"1279247", "label":"someLabel11", "image":"male.png", "refparent":"1185740", "level":"4"},
    {"id":"1316785", "label":"someLabel12", "image":"male.png", "refparent":"1232930", "level":"4"},
    {"id":"1266325", "label":"someLabel13", "image":"male.png", "refparent":"1210593", "level":"5"}
];

var transformed = {};
sampleData.forEach(function(val){
  var ref = val.refparent;
  transformed[ref] = transformed[ref] || [];
  transformed[ref].push(val.id);
});

var output = {}; 
sampleData.forEach(function(val){ 
  output[val.id] = transformed[val.id] || [];
});

document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(output,0,4);
```

Comment: Excellent!! I need to investigate what n*n and 2n complexity means so i can gain more knowledge. (always good to know what someone is saying). Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: @HenryW thanks, glad to help. n is the number of rows. so n*n can potentially take much longer than 2*n